# Remove objects with same ID - Javascript

Tags: javascript

i have an array like this.

```
0: {id: 4, country: Japan},
1: {id: 5, country: Korea},
2: {id: 6, country: Philippines},
3: {id: 6, country: Philippines}
```

How can I remove both record with the same id? so the returned data should look like this.

```
0: {id: 4, country: Japan},
1: {id: 5, country: Korea}
```

How can i fix this? I tried the methods described in a specific topic here but it didn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each element of the array if there are elements equal to it, it is marked as "to be removed" and meanwhile the equal elements are removed. The i element is removed at the end.

```
function removeDuplicates(a){
  for(let i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++){
    let toRemove = false;
    for(let j = 0; j < a.length ; j++){
      if(i != j && a[i].id == a[j].id){
        toRemove = true;
        a.splice(j,1);
      }
    }
    if(toRemove) a.splice(i,1)
  }
  return a;
}
```

Comment: this one works, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

this is another way to do that

```
let data = 
[
{id: 4, country: "Japan"},
{id: 5, country: "Korea"},
{id: 6, country: "Philippines"},
{id: 6, country: "Philippines"}

]; 

data.map((s, i) => {
 if (i>0 &&s.id != data[i- 1].id) {
  return s;
 }else{
  delete data[i- 1];
 }
});
```